# Setting up bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using [single bootstrap carousel](https://bootstrap-ru.com/javascript.php#carousel) and facing one problem. The carousel has several items/images to show, and one of these items must be an active one. Here`s the code:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <!-- Carousel items -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="**active item**">…</div>
    <div class="item">…</div>
    <div class="item">…</div>
  </div>
  <!-- Carousel nav -->
  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

But, I have a one variable for all images in php. I am leaving an active item as blank, and setting loop for item as followingly:

```
   <div class="**active item**">…</div>

 {section name=x loop=$similar_data}
   <div class="item">…</div>
 {/section}
```

How can I set first picture from all pictures for an active one?

[Here`s the link](https://shahar.uz/kvartira/prodaja-kvartira-tashkent-kvartal-ts-5-orientir-gentlemen-pub-139114) to see how my carousel works.

Comment: It would be trivial to change the first item to active with JavaScript. Do you want the code?

Comment: I think, it would be better to choose the first photo from all in php?

Comment: I can't help you with PHP. I haven't touched PHP for many years.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to set the first item active with JavaScript:

```js
const carouselInner = document.querySelector('.carousel-inner');

function makeFirstItemActive() {
  const firstItem = carouselInner.firstElementChild;
  firstItem.classList.add('active');
  console.log('first item:', firstItem);
}

makeFirstItemActive();
```

```html
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="item">first item</div>
  <div class="item">second item</div>
  <div class="item">third item</div>
</div>
```